# String interpolation within ruby comments?

Tags: ruby, yard

Is there a way to interpolate strings in ruby comments?

Something that would enable me to DRY up code documentation like this, for instance:

```ruby
SOME_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Some error message"
# This method returns the following error codes and error messages:
#   1 - {#SOME_ERROR_MESSAGE}
def create
  render(status: 403, json: { error_code: 1, error_message: SOME_ERROR_MESSAGE }.to_json) && (return false)
end
```

Notice the use of `{# }` in the comment here. Is there something available such as this?

Comment: If that is possible, it would mean that YARD evaluates (runs) the Ruby code while parsing. I don't think that is the case.

Comment: Sure you can do it with preprocessing (make your code in `.rb.erb` and compile to `.rb`) but otherwise no, because comments are meant to be statically analyzed

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening comments. If any of you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it as the answer to this question. FCFS